# Calculate Pi on an Android phone

Tags: java, android, pi

I'm trying to make an Android phone calculate n decimals of Pi. For this I'm using this code:

```
public class Pi {

private static final BigDecimal TWO = new BigDecimal(2);
private static final BigDecimal FOUR = new BigDecimal(4);
private String nummer; 

public void pi(final int SCALE) {
    BigDecimal a = ONE;
    BigDecimal b = ONE.divide(sqrt(TWO, SCALE), SCALE, ROUND_HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal t = new BigDecimal(0.25);
    BigDecimal x = ONE;
    BigDecimal y;

    while (!a.equals(b)) {
        y = a;
        a = a.add(b).divide(TWO, SCALE, ROUND_HALF_UP);
        b = sqrt(b.multiply(y), SCALE);
        t = t.subtract(x.multiply(y.subtract(a).multiply(y.subtract(a))));
        x = x.multiply(TWO);
    }

    a.add(b).multiply(a.add(b)).divide(t.multiply(FOUR), SCALE, ROUND_HALF_UP);
    number(a);
}

public void number(BigDecimal a) {
    //nummer = a.toString().length();
    nummer = a.toString();
}

public String returnNum() {
    return nummer;
}

public static BigDecimal sqrt(BigDecimal A, final int SCALE) {
    BigDecimal x0 = new BigDecimal("0");
    BigDecimal x1 = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(A.doubleValue()));

    while (!x0.equals(x1)) {
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = A.divide(x0, SCALE, ROUND_HALF_UP);
        x1 = x1.add(x0);
        x1 = x1.divide(TWO, SCALE, ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }

    return x1;
}
```

This works like a charm on any computer but when I try to run this on my Android tablet it decides that Pi is 0.8 something. Why does this miss calculation occur and how can I make this work?

Comment: When I execute this code with JDK 1.7.0_1 (win32 Oracle VM) calling pi(100) I also get 0.8... as the result.

Comment: Where does ONE come from?  I'm a Java newbie but this doesn't look like working code since I had to make changes to get it to build.  Once I added that, I also got 0.8...

Comment: I just ran it on a desktop machine and got .8472...  I'm on an ubuntu 64-bit machine, if that's relevant, and Java 1.6.  What are you running with that you actually got an approximation of Pi?  Also, I tested by doing Pi myPi = new Pi(); myPi.pi(10); print(myPi.returnNum);  - That's correct?

Comment: more importantly, can you link to the algorithm so we have something to compare the code to?

Comment: @Brad ONE is statically imported from BigDecimal. You need to do a static import: import static java.math.BigDecimal.*;

Comment: what value should contain the ROUND_HALF_UP constant ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a bit from your calculation. The line :

```
a.add(b).multiply(a.add(b)).divide(t.multiply(FOUR), SCALE, ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

is not being assigned to anything. Assign this to something and print that value out and you'll find your calculation works.

```
BigDecimal pi = a.add(b).multiply(a.add(b)).divide(t.multiply(FOUR), SCALE, ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(pi)
```

This gives me the correct answer.

For those that are interested, the algorithm can be found on [**wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm)